# Receipt API integration using razorpay invoices

Tags: razorpay, receipt, flutter-razorpay

I want to create a receipt after the successful payment process by Razorpay and send it to the customer but there is only an invoice to generate the payment link page which I can send via email and SMS so that customer can proceed to pay but I only want to give a payment receipt, how can I fix it. and also I don't want to create a payment page so I can't use a generic payment receipt method.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, what I found from google, there’s no way to sent a invoice/payment receipt to your customer through razorpay automatically with the payment gateway. Although you can use razorpay products like payment pages, links, button.

What I’ve done in my project once a payment is captured, I use a webhook event for same and there I used mail service like sendgrid and use a custom template to send invoices to customers through sendgrid sdk.